# How to set same value for all the text fields with same name attribute using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I see from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541855/how-do-i-set-value-of-a-textbox-using-javascript/51397930) that we can set value for the first element by `document.getElementsByName('Contact0Email')[0].value = email;` and second element by `document.getElementsByName('Contact0Email')[1].value = email;` and so on.

But how to set values for all the text fields with same name attribute?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to loop over elements in form using getElementsByName?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494984/how-to-loop-over-elements-in-form-using-getelementsbyname)

Answer (score 0):

I found it as:

```
var Firstname = document.getElementsByName("Firstname");
    for (var i=0; i < Firstname.length; i++) {
        Firstname[i].value = getAllUrlParams().Firstname;
    }
```

[Javascript change fields value by name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419232/javascript-change-fields-value-by-name)

Answer (score -1):

```
document.querySelectorAll('.selector').forEach(
    function( element ) {
        element.value = 'example@example.com';
    }
);
```

Comment: I want to select the text fields by name. Not class.

Comment: this applies to any css selector, ergo names are possible.

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('Contact0Email')